# $ flutter pub run build_runner build in project with hive not responding

Tags: flutter, dart

When run $ flutter pub run build_runner build in project with hive, it just stops here(i have even waited 2 hours and its not going any further),
i have tried creating a new project specifically for hive implementation. but its the same issue

```
[INFO] Generating build script...
[INFO] Generating build script completed, took 528ms
[WARNING] Deleted previous snapshot due to missing asset graph.
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot......
[INFO] Creating build script snapshot... completed, took 21.3s
[INFO] Initializing inputs
[INFO] Building new asset graph...
[INFO] Building new asset graph completed, took 1.2s
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs....
[INFO] Checking for unexpected pre-existing outputs. completed, took 2ms
[INFO] Running build...
[INFO] Generating SDK summary...
```

this is my class:

```
import 'package:hive/hive.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@HiveType(typeId: 0)
class Person extends HiveObject {
  @HiveField(0)
  int id;
  @HiveField(1)
  String name;
  @HiveField(2)
  DateTime birthDate;
  Person(this.id, this.name, this.birthDate);
}
```

and my pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  hive:
  hive_flutter:
  path_provider:

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner:
  hive_generator:


flutter:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I Was Also facing the same issue and solved it with,*

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

*If that doesn't help you, then try these steps too*

```
flutter clean

flutter pub get

flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

Comment: `packages` and `pub` are means one, you can avoid one

Answer (score 0):

if (dart run build_runner build) not work

(add your file_name.g.dart)eg=> part 'model.g.dart'; in top

and run in terminal

flutter packages pub run build_runner watch --use-polling-watcher --delete-conflicting-outputs

Comment: I don't know this language but please try to improve the quality of your post by using code blocks by using "```" three tildes in a row around the code block elements as well as using full sentences to explain your answer.